# Transition words

Tags: word-usage

There are certainly a plethora of transition words like: however, furthermore, nevertheless, instead, indead, etc. Except for the appearance of these words at the beginning of a sentence, their appearances in the middle of a sentence require some kind of grammatical rules, for example:

> I decided to have a lunch outside; however, I restrained it due to the rainy weather.

The word "however" is put between a semicolon (;) and a comma (,). As a result, I wonder if this rule is true for other words? Even for the words, which appear in the middle of a sentence very seldom, like "furthermore, correspondingly, accordingly"? I inquire this because when I used those words in the middle of some sentences of my essay, my teacher insisted that each of those sentences should have been split into two separate sentences, owing to the fact that the transition words "furthermore, correspondingly, accordingly" are rarely seen in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: In your example, _however_ **is** at the beginning of a sentence. There are two sentences, separated by a semicolon. You only seem to be talking about cases where these conjunctive adverbs are used at the beginning of sentences. They can also appear as parentheticals in the middle of a sentence, but you don't mention any such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Swan in his book "Practical English Usage" states the following:

> If there is a conjunctive adverb linking two independent clauses, you should use a semicolon before *otherwise*.
>
> > *The inhabitants were warned not to leave their houses after 12.00pm; otherwise, they will be shot.*