# Use more Transition words

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I recently integrated Yoast SEO for my blog https://yogixi.com and immediately started getting a lot of these errors `Transition words: Only 23.1% of the sentences contain transition words, which is not enough. Use more of them.` Now the issue is how much I try I am failing to reduce it to the accepted percentage.

For example this paragraph.

> We can access a remote Linux machine using an SSH Client, for example, Putty. We do our work and close the session by closing Putty, but sometimes our SSH client (whether it is Putty or other) closes due to unwanted reasons or maybe we want to keep the session running but also want to pack the laptop to leave from office.

[image]

Almost, the entire paragraph is highlighted in red, prompting me to correct it. I have already gone through this thread [Transition words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338414/transition-words) but still didn't get, how to fix sentences that are missing these.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think your text is pretty well written.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. I also believe same because Grammarly doesn't display any errors.

Comment: I didn't have the slightest idea what _transition words_ meant until I followed the link. I can't imagine why somebody thinks you should bolt them on to your sentences.

Comment: Any checking tool that simply counts the number of transition words in a text without considering the nature of the text can be ignored. The page from which your text comes consists to a large degree in numbered steps.  So transitions are not needed to the extent that they would be in, for example, a persuasive piece about why someone should use Putty. Any checking tool that says baldly "Use more transitions" is unhelpful.

Comment: The only criticism I  would make of your text is that "leave from" is used to specify the point of departure on a journey (as in "he left London from Heathrow") not to say that you need to go away from a current location. Your text should end "...pack the laptop and leave the office". All the stuff about more transition words seems like an invalid criticism to me.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, there is in fact nothing wrong with your writing (well, nothing major ;) we can always pick nits).

The tool you are using appears intended to create a particular style of writing suited to attracting attention via search engines, and in fact this will *spoil* your writing. @Shoe's observation is quite correct: you're not (we hope) writing a puff piece to market something.

**tl;dr** uninstall the tool.

Credits: @hot-licks, @colin-fine, @shoe.

Answer (score 0):

No writing rule is set in stone. These are especially disputable. However, Yoast recommends using transition words because it helps survive in the world of headlinese.

The lines in purple *do* have a transition word. These are considered more coherent than those that do not because these transition smoothly from or to other parts of your text.

> We can access a remote Linux machine using an SSH Client, *for example*, Putty. ... *but* sometimes our SSH client ...

You should be working on the parts not highlighted:

> We do our work and close the session by closing Putty.
>
> It could be installation of software, running a development build or executing automation tests. In such scenarios, installing "Screen" would help us a lot. This tool helps is continuing our session on a remote server, even after closing Putty or shutting down the laptop.

Now, one may choose from the various types of transition words, listed here from [Transition words: why and how to use them](https://yoast.com/transition-words-why-and-how-to-use-them/).

| Transition | Example word/phrase | Example sentence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cause and effect | Therefore, as a result, so, consequently | I’m tired. *Therefore*, I’m going to bed. |
| Clarification | That is to say, in other words, to clarify | We’re letting you go. *In other words*, you’re fired. |
| Contrast | But, however, on the other hand | I am not fond of fruit. *However*, I do like bananas. |
| Example | For example, for instance | In the evening, I like to relax. *For instance*, I enjoy watching TV. |
| Emphasis | Above all, most importantly, certainly | There are many reasons to exercise regularly. *Above all*, it keeps you healthy. |
| Enumeration | Firstly/secondly, further, and, moreover, in addition | Today, I’m going to write a post. *In addition*, I’m recording some video lessons. |
| Time | Meanwhile, during, subsequently, after that | I’ll start by telling you what transition words are. *After that*, I’ll tell you why you should always use them. |
| Similarity | Likewise, similarly, in the same vein | She tried really hard to entertain her guests. *Similarly*, he put all his heart and soul in cooking a great dinner. |
| Summarize/conclude | In conclusion, to sum up, in short | *In conclusion*, transition words are an important aspect of SEO copywriting. |

Of all the sentences in the image, 40% meet the criteria for having a transition word. Because this is more than the recommended 30%, you need not improve there.

However, your [Flesch score](https://yoast.com/flesch-reading) is below the recommended minimum of 60. To perfect this, use shorter, mono or disyllabic words for a lower syllable count per sentence.

Score-based editing might not be the best way to go about traditional writing, which is more about feel, but, as someone who has interned in web content writing, I would say it is the norm.